# How to set a proper layout for GUI in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, jlabel

I want to create a gui, where the window is split in half, one side has the inputs (jlabels and text fields), the other side has the output printed out. Before I add any listeners and what not I ran into a problem where I could create two seperate panels. Can anyone suggest a layout and proper way to use it? By default i only know how to use flowlayout and that wont work. On top of that my textfields wont align with my input boxes.

Comment: I suggest reading [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

Comment: So many layouts and combinations of layouts (nesting JPanels, each with its own layout) could work here, including BorderLayout, BoxLayout, GridLayout, GridBagLayout, MigLayout, GroupLayout.... so much so that your question is verging on being too broad. My recommendation? Experiment! Try a bunch of different options. Play with your code and see what results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two Panels.

```
JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel outputPanel = new JPanel();
```

Use BorderLayout for your Frame.

```
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

Add the Input Panel as WEST child of your frame.

```
frame.add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

Add the output Panel as the EAST child of your frame.

```
frame.add(outputPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

Use Grid Layout for the Input Panel.

```
inputPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(/* appropriate initialization */));
// Add children to inputPanel
```

And appropriate layout for the Output Panel.

```
// Set layout of outputPanel and add its appropriate children.
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `MigLayout`. Try to add panels as given in `Adding Components to the Grid` section of guide. [click here to see guide](http://www.miglayout.com/QuickStart.pdf)
If you are new to java read `head first java`GUI chapter